# How to make a prism with different shapes at each end?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a triangular prism that becomes circular at the other end, but to no avail.

At this stage I have a circle with 3 vertices and another with 16, how would I connect these into a prism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add 13 vertices to your triangle, select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and connect with LoopTools > Bridge (tools tab in T panel). Can't screenshot now.

Comment: Might be worth noting that Loop Tools are an add-on

Comment: integrated and activated in official release i think